# What does max 2 MiB mean?

Tags: support, uploader

When I click the button to add an image to stackexchange websites, it says "max 2 MiB" What does that mean? Is it an amount of megabits? Whats the max amount I can upload (in megabits)?

Comment: It's two [mebibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [128 MByte vs. 128 GByte](http://superuser.com/questions/749658/128-mbyte-vs-128-gbyte)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's 2 mebibytes, where a mebibyte is 1024 kibibytes and a kibibyte is 1024 bytes. At least on Windows, what Windows calls an MB is really MiB. 2 MiB is a tad bigger than 2 megabytes.

Comment: Mebibytes are an abobimination.

Comment: @Deer uh yeah, so ugly...