# "Your image is too large to upload (over 2 MB)." vs. "(max 2MiB)"

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, uploader, regression

Contradictory disclosed max size for images: 2 MB != 2 MiB.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure we had this discussion before but I fail to find the corresponding Q/A

Comment: @rene did you mean https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261925/the-maximum-image-size-one-can-upload-is-2-mib-not-2-mb?rq=1

Comment: Also one has a space and the other doesn't..... consistency!

Comment: Those buttons haven't survived dark mode very well either...

Comment: I can't count how many times this has regressed.

Comment: @S.S.Anne first time I see the issue on the error message AFAIR.

Comment: @Luuklag wasn't about the error message. But yeah this MB vs MiB keeps showing up.

Comment: Technically it's correct. If the file is over 2 MiB, then it's over 2 MB as well.

Comment: Ah I spotted the difference, I stand corrected.

Comment: @JohnDvorak true but it makes the error message less useful and more confusing :)

Comment: If anyone is wondering which is correct (closest) I believe [it actually supports MiBs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269693/282094) as that's been my experience. Usually it's only an issue when uploading .PNGs, as a .JPG that large would either be poorly compressed or of huge dimensions. Even so, some charts with fine fonts would benefit from a slightly larger limit (if there's to be a change). If it's a .JPG that big an additional warning about suggested image dimensions would be a useful addition @AdamLear.

Comment: Ah, good old metric and imperial measurements

Comment: @Rob  thanks, yes last time I tested, max size seemed to be 2 MiB indeed, not 2 MB https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261925/178179 I wish that if the image is above the max size (currently 2 MiB), it would automatically resize (or change compression) to the largest image possible, or close to it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273986/178179

Comment: This was fixed the previous times ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261925/269301), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328796/269301)), so I'm sure it won't take long to fix it again. Not sure why this keeps happening. Thank you for keeping on it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All text referring to file upload size has been changed to `2 MiB`.